# Trying to identify which chemical is responsible for a burned plastic taste in certain flavors

Tags: flavor, flavored-coffee

I used to love hazelnut flavored coffee. One day though, I noticed it smelled and tasted like burned plastic.  I chalked it up to a bad batch, but it turned out, since that day, all (or all that I've tried, including ones that used to be fine) have that smell and taste.

I figured it was something in the artificial flavoring used for hazelnut since actual hazelnuts (raw and roasted) don't have that flavor nor odor to me.

Today I just tried a coconut mocha coffee they had at my office as it looked interesting and I smelled the same exact odor. I tasted it anyway, and got the exact same taste as well. There was nothing hazelnut about this coffee.

So, I'm trying to figure out what exactly it is that I am perceiving as this smell/taste.  It's not actually hazelnuts and it's something that's in multiple flavored coffees, but definitely not all.

It's not coffee itself, and it's not a flavor that's in every flavored coffee (black coffee, cinnamon bun, blueberry, pumpkin spice, so far have all been fine)

Anyone have any idea at all what it could be that I'm tasting that way?

Answer (score 2):

Being ill or recovering from being ill can certainly change your sense of taste. Can you get somebody else to try the coffee you get that smell/taste from to see if they also do? At least you can eliminate you or the coffee.

[Taste Changes - Topic Overview](http://www.webmd.com/oral-health/tc/taste-changes-topic-overview)

Comment: It's definitely me.  It happened like a switch a year ago.  There's nothing wrong with the coffee.